# Center of a maximal subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Is it possible to find a non-abelian group (preferably a finite $p$-group) with the following property?

If M is a maximal subgroup of a group (or finite $p$-group) $G$, then $Z(M)\not \le Z(G)$.

Comment: Did you attempt anything? Have you tried one of the groups you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are two non-abelian groups of order $p^3$ (up to isomorphism). Due to Sylow theorem they both have a subgroup of order $p^2$ (it is well-known, that all groups of order $p^2$ are abelian) and it is not very difficult to prove that their centres have order $p$.